# Using Sub Interactor for an Interactor in SwiftUI - Failed to produce diagnostic for expression

Tags: swift, swiftui, protocols, combine

I have created a simple SubInteractor with @Published var and then there is a MainInteractor using that SubInteractor and a MainView that has access to MainInteractor.
That MainView needs to pass the @Published var down to a subview by accessing it through the MainInteractor.

Using the following code to create a SubInteractor inside MainInteractor gives an error:

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

protocol SubInteractorProtocol {
    var name: String { get set }
}

class SubInteractor: ObservableObject & SubInteractorProtocol {
    @Published var name: String = "name"
}

protocol MainInteractorProtocol {
    associatedtype SubType: ObservableObject & SubInteractorProtocol
    var subInteractor: SubType { get set }
}

class MainInteractor: ObservableObject & MainInteractorProtocol {
    
    @ObservedObject var subInteractor: SubInteractor
    
    init(subInteractor: SubInteractor) {
        self.subInteractor = subInteractor
    }
}

struct NameView: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(name)")
    }
}

struct MainView<Interactor: ObservableObject & MainInteractorProtocol>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var c: Interactor
    var body: some View {
        NameView(name: $c.subInteractor.name)
    }
}
```

I also tried changing the SubInteractorProtocol and SubInteractor to this (but get the same error):

```
protocol SubInteractorProtocol {
    var name: String { get set }
    var namePublished: Published<String> { get }
    var namePublisher: Published<String>.Publisher { get }
}

class SubInteractor: ObservableObject & SubInteractorProtocol {
    @Published var name = "name"
    var namePublished: Published<String> { _name }
    var namePublisher: Published<String>.Publisher { $name }

}
```

Any suggestions about how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this, I use subInteractor and there is no need to use @Published or @ObservedObject on the SubInteractor. I pass the SubInteractor down to the view that needs it instead of passing a published variable owned by SubInteractor.

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class SubInteractor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count = 1
        
    init() {
    }
}


protocol MainInteractorProtocol: ObservableObject {
    var subInteractor: SubInteractor { get set }
}


class MainInteractor: ObservableObject & MainInteractorProtocol {
    
    var subInteractor: SubInteractor

    init(subInteractor: SubInteractor) {
        self.subInteractor = subInteractor
    }
}

struct NameView: View {
    @ObservedObject var s: SubInteractor
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(s.count)")
    }
}
```

And to call it:

```
struct MainView<Interactor: ObservableObject & MainInteractorProtocol>: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var c: Interactor
   var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Button(action: {
               c.subInteractor.count += 1
           }, label: {
               Text("increment")
           })
           NameView(s: c.subInteractor)
       }
   }
}
```